# Keeping scroll position when adding elements on top works in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll

I have a [Meteor app](https://wikimedia.meteorapp.com/) ([source code](https://github.com/mitar/mediawiki-stream)) which has a stream of entries and new entries are being constantly added on top. I am trying to make it so that if an user scrolls down to a particular entry, that entry should stay visible and not move even when more entries are added on top. Adding and removing entries is animated using Velocity.

I have [made code which does that](https://github.com/mitar/mediawiki-stream/blob/master/client/momentum.coffee), but it works only in Firefox, while in Chrome it quickly starts jumping around as more entries are coming. Why is that and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 16):

I'm going to post this since it took me a while to figure out. For me it had to do with the **[Scroll Anchoring](https://wicg.github.io/ScrollAnchoring/)** feature which was introduced as default in **Chrome 56**.

> The `overflow-anchor` property enables us to opt out of **Scroll Anchoring**, which is a browser feature intended to allow content to load above the user's current DOM location without changing the user's location once that content has been fully loaded. [Source](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-anchor)

You might want to try setting `overflow-anchor` to `none`, to opt out of the **Scroll Anchoring** functionality:

```
body {
  overflow-anchor: none;
}
```

[You can find a demo here, showcasing the difference with and without scroll anchoring.](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/oWgENp)

Answer (score 1):

After you insert the elements at the top, you need to manually re-scroll to the correct position:

```
function insertNewElementAtTop(parent, elem) {
  var scrollTopBeforeInsert = parent.scrollTop;
  parent.insertBefore(elem, eParent.firstChild);
  parent.scrollTop = scrollTopBeforeInsert + elem.offsetHeight;
}
```

Comment: I am doing that: `$node = $(node); currentScrollStop = $(window).scrollTop(); $node.insertBefore(next); nodeHeight = $node.outerHeight(true); $(window).scrollTop(currentScrollStop + nodeHeight)`

Comment: @Mitar Just to make sure: what element is the scrollbar on?